# is there a method to update graph on click c3.js?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

i used c3 .js to draw linechart timesseries , i want to add a button when we click on button , we show graph based on cumul instead of val ...
or add a switchery button between val and cumul to show graph based on val or cumul

```
date: ["....","...."]
val : ["..","...",...]
cumul : ["...","...",...]

var c3_chart = c3.generate({                                              
    bindto:div_id,                                                        
    title: {                                                              
        show: false,                                                      
        text: '',                                                         
        position: 'top-center',   
    },                                                                    
    size: {                                                               
        height: parent_height,                                            
    },                                                                    
    padding: {                                                            
        top: 10,                                                          
        right: 50,                                                        
        bottom: 10,                                                       
        left: 50,                                                         
    },                                                                    
    data: {                                                               
        x: 'times',                                                       
        xFormat: date_format, // how the date is parsed                   
        columns: [                                                        
            date,                                                         
            val                                                           
        ],                                                                
        types: {                                                          
            data: 'area-spline'                                           
        },                                                                
         colors: {data: "#58b6a7" },//"rgb(88,182,167)"},                 
         type: 'line',                                                    
        onclick: function (d) {                                           
            var formatTime2 = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d');                  
            var begin=d.x;                                                
            var temp = new Date(d.x);                                     
            var end=temp.setDate(temp.getDate() + 1);                     
            onclick_function(formatTime2(begin),formatTime2(end));        
        },                                                                
    },
```

i want to add a button when we click on button , we show graph based on cumul instead of val ...

Comment: Your d3.js tag is misleading

Comment: Did you already tried something ? Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working ?

Comment: tried to add this code in onclick but not working :  
     this.load({
        columns: cumulativeData
      });